# servlet url is not valid as strava authorization callback domain

Tags: java, servlets, oauth-2.0

I am trying to connect to strava api using Oauth2, the registration of my application requires an authorization callback domain like : http://testapp.com
but I am locally testing this and my url is like : http://localhost:/7001/testapp.com/servlet but strava won't validate this with an error "this filed must be a domain, no slashes or paths", how can I put my servlet url as a callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your authorization callback domain to either `http://localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1`. Then while requesting access you provide Strava with any `redirect_uri` that starts with your callback domain. For example,

```
https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?
  client_id=9
  &response_type=code
  &redirect_uri=http://localhost:7001/testapp.com/servlet
  &scope=write
  &state=mystate
  &approval_prompt=force
```

In case Strava doesn't work well with the *hostname:port* format, you'll need to setup your local application server to run on the default port 80 instead.

```
&redirect_uri=http://localhost/testapp.com/servlet
```

If you're running Tomcat, you'll need to make a change in your *{TOMCAT_HOME}/conf/server.xml* file. If not, check your web application server documentation.